# What's wrong in my MIPS code about merge all separate input into a string?

Tags: string, assembly, mips

```
.data
        string: .space 256
        temp:   .space 4

.text
        la $t0, string
input:  
        li $v0, 8
        la $a0, temp
        li $a1, 4
        syscall
        
        beq $a0, '=', print
        lb $s0, 0($a0)
        sw $s0, ($t0)   
        addi $t0, $t0, 4
        bne $s0, '=', input
    
print:
        li $v0,4
        la $a0, string
        syscall
    
end:
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

I can only store the first character of my input, but I want to store every single input.

input example:
6
+
2
*
3
=

what I want to store in string:
6+2*3=

what I actually store in string:
6

Comment: `sw $s0, ($t0)` store a whole word (little endian in MARS).  Printing that buffer as a C-string will stop on the first `0` byte, after the first character.  Look at memory with the debugger.

Comment: Your first `beq` compares `$a0` to `'='` as if `$a0` holds a character, but it doesn't, it holds an address that refers to a string.  Consider the data types you're using.

Comment: FYI, any language can manipulate bytes/characters and strings, so it is not necessary to think in assembly to do this.  Often it is easier to develop an algorithm first, then once you know what to do, translate that to assembly, rather than developing an algorithm directly in assembly.